# How to write unit test case for cellrenderer in ag-grid

Tags: angular, jasmine, ag-grid, karma-runner

.html

```
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
      [animateRows]="true"
      [pagination]="true"
      [paginationPageSize]="10"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts

```
 public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Source Name',
      field: 'SourceName',
      width: 300,
      cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
        return (
          '<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="noUnderline">' + params.data.SourceName + '</a>'
        );
      }
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Type',
      field: 'Type',
      width: 300,
      cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
        return '<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="noUnderline">' + params.data.Type + '</a>';
      }
    },
    { headerName: 'Location', field: 'Location', width: 350 },
    { headerName: 'Pipeline', field: 'Pipeline', width: 350 }
]
```

component.spec.ts

```
      it('should call the cellrenderer function - SourceName', fakeAsync(() => {
        const cellRenderer = component.columnDefs.find(c => c.field === 'SourceName').cellRenderer as any;
        expect(cellRenderer({data: { 'SourceName': 'OPCUA_Site1' }})).toEqual('OPCUA_Site1');
      }));
```

The unit test throws an error saying "Object is possibly 'undefined'."
Can someone please help me with the correct test case?

Answer (score 1):

The `find` function on an array returns an item of the array or `undefined`. It will return `undefined` if it doesn't find the element.

To fix it, you could protect with an if check:

```
it('should call the cellrenderer function - SourceName', fakeAsync(() => {
        const cellRenderer = component.columnDefs.find(c => c.field === 'SourceName');
        // If it is found (and not undefined), make the assertion.
        if (cellRenderer) {
          expect(cellRenderer({data: { 'SourceName': 'OPCUA_Site1' }})).toEqual('OPCUA_Site1');
      }));
        } else {
          // fail the unit test since we couldn't find the cellRenderer.
          fail();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @AliF50, I will try this and let you know